# Disable editor in WP custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to disable the editor in Wordpress in a specific post type called job_listing. but am not able to disable it so it does not show.

I tried different solutions but they seem to disable visual editor and still allow me to have a html editor.

Comment: `job_listing` is not a default wordpress post_type, how was it created? if it's from a plugin, check for appropriate filters that will allow you to modify the arguments sent to `register_post_type`. There might be settings for this. But this is just guess work, you didn't explain what created this post_type and how. Also, what were those solutions you tired? why don't you explain what you tried so we wont suggest something you did already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the custom post using plugin u have to just edit the custom post type in support option you can disable the editor refer the attatched image

[image]

or second option is

```php
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin.
function disable_editor_for_custom_post_type() {
    // Replace 'your_custom_post_type' with the slug of your custom post type.
    remove_post_type_support('your_custom_post_type', 'editor');
}
add_action('init', 'disable_editor_for_custom_post_type');
```